# One-liner for if in python - why is the result always the last item in the list?

Tags: list, dictionary, for-loop, python-2.x

I have a list (colNames) and I am trying to read each key in the dictionary and iterate thru the list to find the corresponding index wherein the key matches the item in the list

```
colNames = ['First_Name', 'Last_Name', 'ClientID', 'Location']

dict = {'First_Name':'Charlie', 'Last_Name':'Brown', 'ClientID':'23156', 'Location':'H3M 2V4'}

for key, value in dict.iteritems():  

     [item for item in colNames if key==item]

     col = colNames.index(item)

     print item
```

The result is always 'Location' irrespective of the key

Why is that? I assumed it would iterate thru the list and once it finds a match with the key note the item and using colNames.index(item) i could get the index.

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense. You say `python-3.x` but use `.iteritems()` and `print item` and also `item` isn't even defined within the function, it's just defined within the list comprehension!

Comment: I believe it's because the core of your list comprehension is `for item in colNames`, so of course that loop will always end with the last item in `colNames`, which is `'Location'`.

Comment: @Archie. I believe that you would see very different behavior with py3. Please fix your tags

Comment: @schwobaseggl  : The expected result is : if 'key'='list item' print its dictionary value. 
I am writing this output to an excel file, the 'key'='list item' is actually checking the match between the dictionary item's key and the column heading in the excel file. If there is a match, the value of the item is written in the corresponding excel cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
colNames = ['First_Name', 'Last_Name', 'ClientID', 'Location']

_dict = {'First_Name':'Charlie', 'Last_Name':'Brown', 'ClientID':'23156', 'Location':'H3M 2V4'}

for key in _dict:
    print(colNames.index(key))
```

Comment: The question is "why"?

Comment: The expected result is : if 'key'='list item' print its dictionary value. I am writing this output to an excel file, the 'key'='list item' is actually checking the match between the dictionary item's key and the column heading in the excel file. If there is a match, the value of the item is written in the corresponding excel cell

Answer (score 0):

I replaced :

`[item for item in colNames if key==item]:`

with:

```
if key in colNames :
      colNumber = colNames.index(key)
```